# Please explain C14 half-life

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I understand that C14 decays at a given rate. I also interpret this to mean that 100% of the atoms of C14 in an object will all decay at the same right, individually.

So if I have 4 C14 atoms, will they all be gone in a full-life? or will two be 100% in a half-life while the other 2 are 0%?

Please explain how the decay of C14 works.